# ERROR CODE 413 : Your client issued a request that was too large in WEB VIEW

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm loading one url in to webview, it's giving me error code 413 : Your client issued a request that was too large. I have enabled java script. Can any one please help me out.

```
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN); 
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); final 
String mimeType = "text/html"; final String encoding = "UTF-8"; 
webView.loadData(webviewData, mimeType, encoding);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you post the code of webview setup ?

Comment: webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        webView.loadData(webviewData, mimeType, encoding);

Comment: put all the code by editing you question and indent this code with the code function of stackoverflow please !

Comment: The issue happens when the client is trying to upload large file or image or any data, which is beyond the limit set on the server. 

Please, check the HTML file, and evaluate what is it trying to do.